# Excel nested if functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, admin, excel-2016, nested-if

I am trying to write a nested if formula to calculate pricing dependent on number if items sold. Depending on items sold the pricing will change and there are 5 different conditions, I am trying to write it so that when you enter in number of items sold (c12) then it would calculate the price.

The formula that I have right now is:

```
=IF(C12<5,C12*36,IF(AND(C12<=5,C12<=10),C12*34)*IF(AND(C12<=11,C12>=30),C12*31,IF(AND(C12>=31,C12<=30),C12*26)*IF(C12<=51,C12*20)))
```

The range from below 5 works however any ranges above do not work. What is my issue and how do I fix this?

Thank you,

Comment: The reason the formula does not work is because your first IF looks for C12 values under 5.  The second IF is called only if the value is 5 or above, but the AND requires only values <= 5.  It will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use CHOOSE(MATCH())

```
=C12 * CHOOSE(MATCH(C12,{0,5,11,31,51}),36,34,31,26,20)
```

If you want IF(): You have your `>` and `<` backwards.  You also do not need all the AND():

```
=IF(C12<5,C12*36,IF(C12<=10,C12*34,IF(C12<=30,C12*31,IF(C12<=50,C12*26,C12*20))))
```

Answer (score 0):

your formula looks off, so i infer that your "rates" look like this:

```
qty amount
0   $36
5   $34
10  $32
20  $30
30  $25
50  $20
```

my opinion : you should look into using vlookup instead.

create a worksheet with your rates data and structure it like how i did above, with the quantity on the leftmost, followed by the rate per quantity, then on the worksheet that you are doing calculation, use the VLOOKUP formula in the following manner:

`vlookup ( qty , qty:amount , 2 , true )`

( replace the names with your cells and columns )

per the vlookup documentation, please ensure your quantity and rates are sorted in ascending order ; means do not make it jumbled like :

```
qty amount
0   $36
30  $25
10  $32
5   $34
20  $30
50  $20
```